# how to parse field value without parsing record id with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my database one project has many tasks. I was able to give the edit option for each record by parsing the record id when the update button is clicked. But as one project has many task now I need to parse the projectname when the button clicked and show all the tasks related to that project. Can Somebody help me?
This is the button with record
[image]

This is the code

```
            <table class="table table-lg">
                <thead >
                    <tr class="filters">


                        <th class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project" disabled></th>
                        <th class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client" disabled></th>
                        <th class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task " disabled></th>
                        <th class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" disabled></th>
                        <th class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Create Date and Time" disabled></th>
                        <th class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date and Time" disabled></th>  
                        <th class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Due Date and Time" disabled></th>


                        <th class="col-lg-1"> Edit</th>
                        <th class="col-lg-1"> Delete</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
              <?php
                if(isset($view_data) && is_array($view_data) && count($view_data)): $i=1;
                foreach ($view_data as $key => $data) { 
                ?>
                <tr <?php if($i%2==0){echo 'class="even"';}else{echo'class="odd"';}?>>


                    <td><?php echo $data['projectname']; ?></td>  


                    <td><?php echo $data['cname']; ?></td>

                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext']; ?></td>    
                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext1']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext2']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext3']; ?></td>   

                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext4']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['mytext5']; ?></td>   






                    <td><a class="btn btn-warning" role="button" href="<?php echo site_url('Task/edit_data/'. $data['id'].''); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>  Edit</a></td> 





                     <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo site_url();?>/Task/delete_data/<?php print($data['id']);?>">
   <img  src='' title="Delete"  onClick="return doconfirm();" />
</a></td>









                </tr>
                <?php
                    $i++;
                      }
                    else:
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="center" >No Records Found..</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>

            </tbody>                
            </table>
```

Comment: Maybe clean up the code in your question, showing only the relevant parts. For me, I use a lot of "data-" attributes, as they're easy to get with jQuery. If you were using jQuery, it'd be as easy as using `$(this).attr('data-id');` assuming you added the data-id attributes with PHP.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the edit button is clicked ? Do you just want to show all the tasks related to the selected project row ?

Comment: @SH_ yes I want to show all tasks reated to that project ..Not only the particular record

Comment: Do you just want to show the tasks or be able to edit them as well? Maybe, Edit the project (which shows all tasks) and then Edit project tasks ?

Comment: @SH_ yes I want to edit them

Comment: @SH_ I think it won't work.. I want to catch the project name when the button is clicked and button click will redirect into a edit page where all tasks are shown based on the project name